# Summer Mathematics Workbooks for Elementary and Middle School

Tags: self-learning, summer

There is a wide variety of summer mathematics workbooks available for students in elementary and middle school (see [here](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=summer%20math%20workbook)). With summer coming up, these books seem to be available everywhere. Thus my questions are:

- **Is there any evidence that suggests summer workbooks are beneficial?**
- **If so, which ones are the best?**

Comment: Please describe the type of student you'd like to help with this.

Comment: Yes, please be more specific with your questions.  Those who want to answer may need more background information.

Answer (score 4):

What exactly do you want to accomplish? If it is helping a child who did poorly, I'd guess the most important ingredient is a patient tutor (probably with the same texts used during the year). If they are interested in looking deeper, perhaps a text book isn't ideal. If it is skipping ahead, better let them have their well-deserved vacation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, many students simply won't *want* to learn more math during the summer, the chance that students will be more distracted is higher.

You have to consider **who** it will be beneficial to before considering **if** it will be beneficial.  A student who needs the extra practice for memory may want to use the books.  A student who is failing or struggling may also want to use the books.

Just throw the books at them and expect them to learn?  Of course not!  I personally recommend doing math-related activities, possibly show more applications of math.  You may find many [applications of math here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications)

Personally, as a student, books?  +Math?  During summer?  You can see what I'm thinking, can't you?  A student doesn't like to study through books, most students don't **want** to study math, and studying during the summer is generally a child's nightmare!  Make it **fun**, that's the key.